# Scala XML literal generation with for-yield

Tags: xml, scala

Is there any way to generate XML using the literal syntax as such:

```
<a>
{
  for (i <- Range(1, 3)) yield {
    <b>{i}</b>
  }
}
</a>
```

that will return

```
<a><b>1</b><b>2</b></a>
```

i.e. I want to use just a single compound statement which will somehow return the complete XML literal.

The only way I know is to do it in two steps: in the first step the for-yield statement will return IndexedSeq or something similiar which then in the second step I have to convert it to scala.xml.Elem. That's OK, but I get the feeling that you can be more concise - nearly as concise as what I proposed in my code above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you posted works just fine...

If you want it to be more concise in terms of typing, you could use an inner statement of

```
(1 to 3).map{i => <b>{i}</b>}
//or
for(i<-1 to 3) yield <b>{i}</b>
```

So then you would just have this:

```
val xml = <a>{ (1 to 3).map{ i => <b>{i}</b> } }</a>
```

Which gives

```
xml: scala.xml.Elem = <a><b>1</b><b>2</b><b>3</b></a>
```

Comment: My bad, the comprehension returns a Vector of Elements, which I assume won't be accepted.I don't understand how scala compiler can automatically convert that into something that can be accepted into the literal syntax definition.

Comment: As far as I know, anything that can be implicitly converted to a `NodeSeq` can go in the `<a>{ ... }</a>`. (This is just my assumption; somebody correct me if I'm wrong)

Answer (score 1):

Do you specifically want to use the for comprehension? If not, this should give you the output you are looking for:

```
<a>{
  (Range(1, 3)).map{ vl => 
     <b>{vl}</b>
  }
}</a>
```

Comment: I have not understood the intrinsics of map or flatMap completely, but I will look into it, this one's are also very elegant.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the for syntax, you need an implicit conversion from Seq[Node] to NodeSeq. I would write down the code, but I am on my phone right now...